# applying an image filtering technique on 'selected' pixels in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, 3d, filtering, threshold

The feature extraction step of my algorithm, applies some filter on a "3D" image and use the value of filtered pixels as the feature of original pixels of image.

My problem is that I need the feature of only small subset of pixels(threshold-ed pixels), not all of the image. and it is time consuming to filter all of the image, instead of only some pixels.

My question is how can I filter only selected pixels of an image? Is there any matlab function for this purpose?(I think I can not use imfilter)

Thank you.

Comment: Can you describe the filter? It will be easier to understand how to help you.

Comment: Is your filter 3D as well, or do you run it on slices?

Comment: The filter is eigen-value of hessian matrix of each pixel. for each hessian entry(e.g. Ixy, Ixx, Iyz,...), first I filter image using gaussian filter and next compute the image gradient in the desired direction(x,y or z).

Comment: my filter is 3D, The result of 3D filter is not equivalent to applying a 2D filter on slices.

Comment: www.tecn.upf.edu/~afrangi/articles/miccai1998.pdf

Comment: If it is a Gaussian, it is separable, which mean that it can be done first on X, then on Y and finally on Z. I am not sure about Hessian.

Comment: If one of the answers helped you achieve your task, you might want to accept it. Thanks.

Comment: the problem is not solved yet.

Answer (score 4):

Use `roifilt2`. The following code was taken directly from [Matlab Documentation site](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/roifilt2.html)

```
I = imread('eight.tif');
```

First, define the region of interest:

```
c = [222 272 300 270 221 194];
r = [21 21 75 121 121 75];
BW = roipoly(I,c,r);
```

In your case, `BW` is already defined, so you can skip the previous step.

Now, apply the filter:

```
H = fspecial('unsharp');
J = roifilt2(H,I,BW);
figure, imshow(I), figure, imshow(J)
```

Comment: Thank you! The roifilt2 is exactly what I wanted. but I forgot to mention that my image is 3D! :(

Answer (score 2):

Here is a fast matrix operation in Matlab that applies a threshold to the image:

```
% let's assume i is your image (matrix)
thresh = 60; % set the threshold for pixel values
i = uint16(i > thresh) .* i; % adjust uint16 to your: class(i)
```

This will set all pixels to `0` which are below the threshold.
If you want to apply the filter to a smaller area afterwards, you can then check which columns and rows of your image contain values larger than zero and crop the image accordingly or define a region of interest using [`roipoly`](http://www.mathworks.de/help/toolbox/images/ref/roipoly.html).

Comment: Thank you, the fast thresholding technique is very useful in my program. roipoly & roifilt2 can do the work, but for 2D images. Sorry, I forgot to mention that my image is 3D.